# How to read this file into PHP - Not Working

Tags: php, xml

I am looking for some help with a project I am doing, using php to read in an xml file. I have spent the last 35 Hours reading everywhere but to no avail. Basically, I am looking for feedback on how to read this piece of xml code into PHP. I am not majorly comfortable with PHP so may not understand the syntax or commands fully. I can take in single elements but I can't when it has the Id part like below.

```
      <OutputLine Id="3" Text="Output Line 3">
        <Name>Line 3</Name>
        <Type>0</Type>
        <Pulse>False</Pulse>
        <Delay>0</Delay>
      </OutputLine>
```

I am looking for the  information for my php website.

If anyone could help me I would be so grateful

Comment: Google for SimpleXML, or DOMDocument.

Comment: I have done this, still cannot get it going. I just need to get the part figured with the id tag and I can finish the rest myself

Comment: The `Id="3"` tag is a CSS style reference. Have you set up your CSS styles yet?

Answer (score 0):

This how you do it

Save this as **note.xml** in the same directory where your php code resides

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <OutputLine Id="3" Text="Output Line 3">
        <Name>Line 3</Name>
        <Type>0</Type>
        <Pulse>False</Pulse>
        <Delay>0</Delay>
      </OutputLine>
```

save this below as **xml.php** and run the code

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("note.xml");
echo $xml->Name . "<br>";
echo $xml->Type . "<br>";
echo $xml->Pulse . "<br>";
echo $xml->Delay;
?>
```

**Your output will be**

```
Line 3
0
False
0
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want to print the result as object you can try this. <?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("note.xml");
print_r($xml);
?>

Comment: Thanks you soooooo much for taking the time to reply, my problem is that it is a significantly large xml file. It's from a Cognex Vision job. I need to be able to reference, this type of the xml file first; <OutputLine Id="3" Text="Output Line 3"> because there are lots of them. I'm trying to find them so I can insert the information they hold, into a website. So, I can show Pass/Fail results of parts